# ZF2: Groups of modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-config

I'm in the process of learning ZF2 and planning an application.

I would like to have 1 application with several groups of modules.  Each group of modules could contain up-to 20+ modules.

I won't be able to guarantee a unique name for any of the modules for the whole app, but i can guarantee their uniqueness within their module group.

Ideally route requests to module groups using a Hosting router.

e.g.
http://admin.mysite.com/foo/ => 'Admin/Foo/Index/Index',

http://special.mysite.com/foo/ => 'Special/Foo/Index/Index'

**Idea #1**

I was hoping to use a different module_path for each module group and namespacing the module path around the module group to determine uniqueness of the module's class.  But modules sent to the module_autoloader only seem to pay any attention to the first part of any strings passed.

e.g.

```
array('modules' => array(
 'Admin\Admin','Admin\Bob','Admin\Users'
));
```

This gets strange behaviour I don't understand:

- All three will point to the correct module controller but they load the view for Admin\Admin (which is first in the module list) instead of their own.
- I.E. /users, loads Admin\Users\IndexController but with the view script Admin\Admin\view\admin\Index\index.phtml

I've managed to fix this with some small alterations to the templateInjecter but it seems messy.

**Idea #2**

Just prefix module names to their subdirectory e.g.

```
namespace AdminAdmin\Controller,
class  IndexController {}
```

**Thoughts**

- namespaces would be preferred to class prefixes
- we're trying to automate as much of this as possible instead of using hardcoded routes for each module
- it could make sense to use multiple applications that share a module for authentication via a common cookie host/memcache and db, etc...
- route each module to a certain subdomain using the hosting type routes inside a treeRouteStack of the modules controllers etc...

**Question:**

- Is their a best practice for this situation or similar and why?

Comment: Are you sure you understood ZF2 Modules correctly? It seems to me that you're doing assumptions as if you were working with ZF1 modules since in ZF2 there is no thing like "routing to modules".

Comment: forgive my terminology but i've many *working* applications where routes point to specific modules in zf2.

Comment: A module in ZF2 is a functionality, not something you route to :\ You can route to controllers... If you then inflect their names it is another question, but keep the concepts separate, it helps you understanding how to unleash the power of the entire "merging" mechanism of the module manager ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is that you're really asking two questions:

## (1) Namespacing modules

This is possible natively with ZF2.  Modules in ZF2 are basically just PHP namespaces, so a module named `Foo\Bar` is perfectly acceptable, and by default the module loader will look for it's module class in `module/Foo/Bar` then `vendor/Foo/Bar`.

For example, if you wanted to create a module Anvil and under the namespace Acme, you would create directory `module/Acme/Anvil`, and inside it create a `Module.php` file:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Anvil;

class Module
{
    /* module class code goes here */
}
```

In your application's `config/application.config.php` you would add `Acme\Anvil` to the `modules` key:

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Acme\Anvil',
    ),
    // Remaining bits of config array are unchanged
);
```

## (2) Dynamically-loading modules

One approach you could take would be to modify your site's bootstrap `index.php` to modify the configuration on-the-fly based on the hostname. For example, using [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) you would set up your `application.config.php` file like so:

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        // Other modules common to all sites go here
    ),
    'sites' => array(
        'site-one.mydomain.com' => array(
            'modules' => array(
                'ModuleOne',
                'ModuleTwo',
            ),
        ),
        'site-two.mydomain.com' => array(
            'modules' => array(
                'ModuleThree',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    // Remaining bits of config array are unchanged
);
```

To make this work we make a slight modification to `public/index.php` to intercept the configuration array loaded from `config/application.config.php` and reconfigure the `modules` key:

```
// Pick host out of request
$hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// Load application configuration
$applicationConfig = require 'config/application.config.php';

// Merge site-specific modules into loaded modules array
$applicationConfig['modules'] = array_merge(
    $applicationConfig['modules'],
    $applicationConfig['sites'][$hostname]['modules']
);

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init($applicationConfig)->run();
```

This approach provides an easy way to change which modules are loaded for a particular hostname, but can easily be extended to allow site-specific configuration file autoloading and site-specific module directories as well.

Comment: great idea on 2 that's awesome! i'll report back with how it goes.

for 1 though, when you use this method, the wrong views are loaded (e.g. in your suggestion, it would look for a view for 'Acme/Index/Index/ whilst still loading the controller for Anvil) but it can be fixed with an extended templateInjecter.

Comment: Word of warning: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] will not be available when running from CLI. Otherwise this is an excellent idea!